# How can I use FastMember to get the properties of a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, dynamic, fastmember

I have the following object:

```
dynamic person = new {Id = 1, Name = "SpiderMan"};
```

I need to be able to iterate through the property names e.g. `"Id"`, `"Name"`.

I also need to be able to achieve this in the most efficient way therefore I chose to use [FastMember](https://code.google.com/p/fast-member/) however it's api does not allow me to iterate through the properties.

Any ideas?

**[UPDATE]**

Thanks to Marc I managed to achieve what I wanted using:

```
dynamic person = new { Id = 1, Name = "SpiderMan" };
MemberSet members = TypeAccessor.Create(person.GetType()).GetMembers();
foreach (Member item in members)
{
    // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the scenario you show, `TypeAccessor.Create(obj.GetType())` and `GetMember()` should work fine, since that type is fine for reflection.

In the more general case: that's a fair question - I honestly can't remember whether FastMember exposes this for true dynamic types, but one important consideration here is that by the very nature of dynamic objects, *the set of properties may not even be enumerable* - i.e. the code could respond to `obj.Whatever` on the fly, without knowing about `Whatever` in advance. For the object you actually have, however, simple reflection is your best bet. The scenario you show does not need `dynamic`.

Comment: Tnx Marc, `GetMembers()` works great for my scenario. Any plans for migrating the source code from GoogleCode over to GitHub? Once again tnx for this brilliant library.